# Access cookies set on subdomain from parent

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, security, cookies

I am trying to access a cookie set on a subdomain (`small.example.org`) from the parent domain (`example.org`) and I would like to do this from a bit of Javascript within the page.

First of all I am setting a cookie for the domain `small.example.org`

```
document.cookie = "name=Mike; domain=small.example.org"
```

When I load `small.example.org` I can successfully see the cookie that I just set. When loading `example.org` I cannot see any cookies from `small.example.org`. Maybe not that surprising.

So I figured I need to make a request to the subdomain to include something onto the main domain, a script tag.

```
<script src="small.example.org/script.js"></script>
```

Now when I load `example.org` with the request to the script tag and have a look in the browser, I can see the cookie from `small.example.org`.

But when I try to access it from Javascript using `document.cookie`, I get nothing.

Is this the expected behavior? I thought you cannot access cookies from Javascript only if they had the `HTTPOnly` flag set.

Is there a way to go around this? The example above is very close to my actual use case scenario and unfortunately I cannot play too much with the architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior.

JavaScript can only access a cookie that if the `domain` of the cookie is either:

- An exact match for the hostname of the current page
- A substring of the hostname of the current page

`example.org` can't read cookies for `small.example.org` (although the reverse is not true).

Note that the Origin for JavaScript is determined by the URL of the HTML document the JS is running in, not by the URL that the JS was loaded from.

You can either:

- Change the `domain` specified when you set the cookie
- Dynamically generate the JS file on the server and insert the data using server-side programming (the browser will send the cookie in the HTTP request header when requesting the JS URL because the domains match).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I considered both the suggestions above before but unfortunately none are an option because I don't have control over how that cookie is set and the JS file will be served from a CDN. I'm a bit stuck.